# How can I only download the build plan for a specific resolver using stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

```
Step 3/3 : RUN cd /build && stack --resolver lts-14.27 build
 ---> Running in 0cbce6fc5f44
Downloading lts-14.27 build plan ...
Downloaded lts-14.27 build plan.
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/) ...
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading root
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading timestamp
Downloading snapshot
Downloading mirrors
Cannot update index (no local copy)
Downloading index
```

How can I **only** download the build plan for a specific resolver?

The reason why, is so that when building a docker container if the `stack build` command fails, I can fix things and not need to download the build plan each time. So effectively looking for a way to cache this.

Answer (score 0):

As a slight workaround you can install one specific library with the resolver (which seems to download the build plan as well):

```
stack install --resolver lts-14.27 aeson
```